# How to implement a flash based jabber client?

Tags: flash, iframe, xmpp, polling

we are trying to develop a flash based jabber client.  How can we minimise the issue of polling to the server when a new page is loaded without implementing an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at storing some data on the client side.  This is often done with flash games to save progress, etc.  With Jabber there is less of a need to work out "cheat" detection with this data, as there would be with a game.

Another option might be to work with the LocalConnection class to run two Flash applets, one that will reload with the page and one that runs in a hidden frame.  The hidden applet will store most of the info to reinitialize the main applet.

The other would be to eliminate the issue all together, and do your page updates via AJAX or similar, instead of reloads.